# How to access multiple URLs in a single AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-studio, android-asynctask, httpurlconnection

I'm a novice in Android programming and I was wondering whether it's possible to connect to multiple URLs using a single AsyncTask(70 different URLs). At the moment, I'm only able to connect to one URL through the use of HttpURLConnection.

```
class MyAsyncTaskClass extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
{

    private String rez;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }



    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {

        try {
            ////////....


            URL url = new URL(("url")); 
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.connect();


            /////////////////

        } catch (Exception e) {
            rez = "false";
        }


        return rez;
    }





    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String rez) 
    {



    }





}
```

Comment: You can do this by using thread pool executor. write thread pool executor and pass you asynctask instances to it. it will execute them in parallelly.

Comment: Thread pool executors seem to have a limit since I can only run 6 instances of asynctask simultaneously, but I need to run 70 instances. Is there any other solution which you may be aware of?

Comment: try with increasing threads count in pool

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you would like to access all there 70 links at the same time (too much connections at the same time will make your connection not responding well), but I think you prefer to execute it one by one.

Why not creare a function like:

```
public String connection(String url) {
        URL cURL = new URL(url); 
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) cURL.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.connect();
        rez = ..........
        return rez;
}
```

and then use:

```
public List<String> doInBackground() {
        final ArrayList<String> cResult = new ArrayList<>();
        cResult.add(connection(url1));
        cResult.add(connection(url2));
        cResult.add(connection(url3));
        ...
        return cResult;
}
```

In this way you are accessing all links one_by_one.

However it seems you miss the part that GETs the results....